# Assign 2 Values to each radio button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign 2 values to each radio button, to output in 2 fields. But it doesn't work. Here the code im using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function check(browser) {
        document.getElementById("answer").value=browser;
    document.getElementById("answerB").valueB=browser;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <p>What's your favorite browser?</p>
    
    <form>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)"     value="400mb",  valueB="600mb">Internet Explorer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)"     value="600mb",  valueB="700mb">Firefox<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)"     value="500mb",  valueB="500mb">Opera<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)"     value="500mb",  valueB="500mb">Google Chrome<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)"     value="300mb",  valueB="300mb">Safari<br>
    <br>
    PC Min Ram Requirement is: <input type="text" id="answer" size="20">
    Mac Min Ram Requirement is:  <input type="text" id="answerB" size="20">
    </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code by using [string.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), and without any external libraries. You also had a reference error trying to access `valueB` on the target `input`.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                function check(browser) {
                    var splitValues = browser.split(';');
                    document.getElementById("answer").value=splitValues[0];
                    document.getElementById("answerB").value=splitValues[1];
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        
        <p>What's your favorite browser?</p>
        
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)"     value="400mb;600mb">Internet Explorer<br>
            <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)"     value="600mb;700mb">Firefox<br>
            <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)"     value="500mb;500mb">Opera<br>
            <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)"     value="500mb;500mb">Google Chrome<br>
            <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)"     value="300mb;300mb">Safari<br>
            <br>
            PC Min Ram Requirement is: <input type="text" id="answer" size="20">
            Mac Min Ram Requirement is:  <input type="text" id="answerB" size="20">
        </form>
        
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few different issues here.
First, the `answerB` text field needs to have its `value` set, not `valueB` set. Second, you are setting both to the same value.
So, instead of passing `this.value` into the `check` function, just pass `this`. Then you can use `.getAttribute('valueB')` to access your custom property.

Also, don't put commas in html tags. I removed those from your `<input>` tags.

See below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function check(browser) {
        document.getElementById("answer").value=browser.value;
        document.getElementById("answerB").value=browser.getAttribute('valueB');
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <p>What's your favorite browser?</p>
    
    <form>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this)" value="400mb" valueB="600mb">Internet Explorer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this)" value="600mb" valueB="700mb">Firefox<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this)" value="500mb" valueB="500mb">Opera<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this)" value="500mb" valueB="500mb">Google Chrome<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this)" value="300mb" valueB="300mb">Safari<br>
    <br>
    PC Min Ram Requirement is: <input type="text" id="answer" size="20">
    Mac Min Ram Requirement is:  <input type="text" id="answerB" size="20">
    </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set value by using `data-` property like,

```
data-value="400mb" data-valueB="600mb"
```

That is,

```
<input type="radio" class = "radiobutton" onclick="check(this)" name="browser" data-value="400mb" data-valueB="600mb" />
```

Then you can access in the `check` function using `jQuery` like,

```
    function check(rb) {
       document.getElementById("answer").value = $(rb).data('value');
       document.getElementById("answerB").value = $(rb).data('valueB');
    }
```

or,

```
$('.radiobutton').click(function () {
            document.getElementById("answer").value = $(this).data('value');
            document.getElementById("answerB").value = $(this).data('valueB');
}
```

Comment: I was too slow :) was about to answer the same

Comment: This answer isn't very helpful, since the OP isn't using jQuery.

Comment: The `$()` function is jQuery, so both your answers still use jQuery. Perhaps you should just declare that this is how to do it if you want to use jQuery. Then this answer would be fine.

Comment: @forgivenson : Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

a pure js solution:

some notes: if you pass this.value to the function then you cant access valueB anymore, pass just the entire element. To set the value use just theTargetElement.value not value and valueB ( thats just wrong ). Dont know why you ve a comma after value ( thats wrong too )

```js
function check(browser) {
  document.getElementById("answer").value = browser.getAttribute("value");
  document.getElementById("answerB").value = browser.getAttribute("valueB");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this)" value="400mb" valueB="600mb">Internet Explorer
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this)" value="600mb" valueB="700mb">Firefox
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this)" value="500mb" valueB="500mb">Opera
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this)" value="500mb" valueB="500mb">Google Chrome
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this)" value="300mb" valueB="300mb">Safari
  <br>
  <br>PC Min Ram Requirement is:
  <input type="text" id="answer" size="20">Mac Min Ram Requirement is:
  <input type="text" id="answerB" size="20">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code have some problems.

1) you need to pass two values (or the element itself) to the function

```
onclick="check(this)"
```

this is because you're just passing the "value" attribute to the function.

2) you need to retrieve "valueB" as a normal attribute. the property "valueB" doesn't exists and so is currently undefined.

```
    function check(element) {
        document.getElementById("answer").value=element.value;
        document.getElementById("answerB").value=element.getAttribute("valueB");
    }
```

in the function check you're also trying to set "valueB" property of the element "answerB", which doesn't make sense (you need to set the normal value to the textbox :))